# How to convert 1 letter from uppercase to lowercase that isn't the first letter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following:

```
var test = "deskLight";
console.log(test.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])([a-z])/g, "$1_" + "$2".toLowerCase() + "$3" )));
```

Result is desk_Light

I want desk_light

Comment: *`"$2".toLowerCase()`* - that's not how `replace` works. Lowercasing the string `$2` leads to just `$2`. You need a callback here.

Comment: `.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])(?=[a-z])/g, function($0,$1,$2,$3) {
  return $1+"_" + $2.toLowerCase(); 
})`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `replace()` [function callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) that takes `match` as parameter.

```js
text = 'deskLight'.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])([a-z])/g, function(match)
    {
        return match[0] + '_' + match[1].toLowerCase() + match[2];
    }
)

console.log(text)
```

Or even simpler solution by **@RobG**.

```js
text = 'deskLight'.replace(/(^[a-z]*)(.*$)/,'$1_$2').toLowerCase()

console.log(text)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed!